# Why Firefox and Chrome insist on using HTTPS for a manually typed non-SSL website

Tags: apache, google-chrome, firefox, redirect, ssl

I would appreciate some help to understand what is going on: both Firefox and Chrome are failing to load my non-SSL website, say subdomain.example.com, with the following SSL errors (both on ubuntu 14.04 i386):

- FF30: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long
- Chrome 35: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This started to occur after I set (and follow) a redirect (302) to SSL on the parent domain, say http://example.com to https://example.com. It gets back to normal after a full cache clean on the browser. But as soon as I access the parent domain I get the problem on the subdomain.

I have never entered the subdomain URL with the "https://" scheme prefix. I don't usually type any prefix and it is happening even if I explicitly prefix with "http://". And it is not only on the address bar, the same happens for links.

I am very confident that there is nothing wrong with the non-SSL site on the subdomain.

I thought about filling a bug report but it is unlikely this is a bug in both browsers and more likely I am missing something.

It there any rule that if a website on a given domain supports SSL (or redirects http to https), then sites on subdomains are assumed to do as well?

I later found the cause of the SSL errors. But the problem still persists (now the message is connection refused):

Apache web server was configured to listen on both ports 80 and 443, but with no "SSLEngine on" clause. This effectively makes it serve plain HTTP on port 443.

It is worth to mention that this Apache configuration mistake is not that hard to fall into. Actually, in the default Ubuntu configuration (possibly the same for Debian), it is just a matter of enabling/loading the SSL module (and not providing a site configuration that uses SSL).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It's not about programming but it is strongly related to software development. It's usually up to the programmer to set STS configuration for a web app (in my case it was on spring security). The question is about the understanding of the HTTP protocol features and how to fix a misconfigured webapp. However it also relates to system administration / dev-ops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found the cause. The ssl site on the parent domain is including the following STS response header:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
```

That triggers the browser behavior by spec.

Comment: Another thing that can cause this is a 301 redirect from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`. It can happen quite frequently when people try out `mod_rewrite`/redirect configurations directly with 301 (better to try with 302 for this reason, I think).

Comment: I used to have a 301 redirect but changed to 302. Why would a 301 redirect affect a subdomain?

Comment: @PerdoPedruzzi, you're right 301 shouldn't affect a subdomain as such, but if the browser has visited that subdomain with a 301 before, it would tend to remember it (whatever you've changed since).

Comment: This isn't what caused it for me. I think it's something to do with SPDY support.

Comment: The obvious solution is to use https on the subdomain too.

If the main domain certificate does not support wildcard domains, get a free certificate from letsencrypt.